# How to process infinite sequence with Repa or Accelerate?

Tags: haskell

I'm just started to learn Haskell and my question may be a trivial one, so please sorry for disturb.

So, imagine I have a real infinite data source (stdin for instance) and I want to process data with use of parallel facilities of Repa or Accelerate. Both of them used arrays (finite data structures). It seems to me that will deal with sequence of arrays in my code, but I really don't know what to do then I need some data from one array and the next one to calculate something.

So, I mean, how can I calculate `y = phase(a[i] * conj a[i+1])` for the all input, where `a` is infinite stream of complex numbers.

Answer (score 3):

Repa and Accelerate, as you've mentioned, are both designed to work on fixed size arrays and matrices. These are batch-oriented algorithms and they are based around many optimizations which are only available when working from fixed bits of memory.

For "infinite" data you need a streaming (or "online") algorithm. The one you've described is streamable as it only requires a finite window. You could translate a streaming algorithm into a large number of small batch steps by computing the phase using Repa for each and every pair of inputs `(a[i], a[i+1])` that stream in, but you may lose out on speed due to the large amount of boxing and copying required to move each small chunk to the contiguous memory array.

To compare, you can use something like `pipes` to generate a fast streaming algorithm.

```
import Pipes
import Data.Complex

type ComplexPair = (Complex Double, Complex Double)

pairOff :: Monad m => Pipe a (a, a) m r
pairOff = await >>= forever . go where
  go x = await >>= \y -> yield (x, y)

compute :: Monad m => Pipe ComplexPair Double m r
compute = do
  (ai, ai1) <- await
  yield (phase $ ai * conjugate ai1)

run :: Monad m => Pipe (Complex Double) Double m r
run = pairOff >-> compute
```

Then `run` can be fed by an infinite streaming input source and dump into whatever the next step of your processing pipeline is. These sources can be Monadic or, if `m ~ Identity`, pure.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, you can't use Repa or Accelerate directly with an infinite stream of data.  It's designed to operate on vectors, which is a different kind of data structure.  There are ways around this, and you have a few options for how to do it:

1. Read in a fixed number of values, construct a vector with it, perform the calculations, and push the values downstream again, iteratively processing chunks of data at a time.  You would have to figure out what you want the chunk size to be, but it would give you the optimal performance during the calculation.  Unfortunately, this means you'll be losing efficiency for all those read-construct steps.  In fact, that would be the step I would be most worried about parallelizing, since you could be performing those steps while the previous chunk is being processed.
2. Forget about using a vector library and turn to the Pipes library.  It is designed to process streams of data in constant memory and gets pretty good performance.  With the `pipes-concurrency` package, you can write a stream processor that reads in data and processes it in parallel.  You won't have the efficiency of vectors, but it'll be easier to handle your infinite stream of data efficiently while using minimal RAM.
3. Implement it with lists first, lazily processing each element and using regular Haskell functions to do so.  You won't get the benefits of speed or memory usage, but it'll be easy to write.  Once you have the concept down, you can decide if you need the efficiency of vectors or streams and then run a benchmarking tool to determine where your bottlenecks are before trying to optimize.

Personally, I would start with 2. or 3., then figure out if my program is slow enough to warrant using vectors.  It may be that you could get that extra performance from vectors, but unless you're utilizing a GPU, this isn't likely.

Comment: It's kind of ironic because under the hood the `vector` library does have the machinery for infinite and effectful streams since its stream fusion representation (see [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.10.9.1/docs/Data-Vector-Fusion-Stream-Monadic.html#t:Stream)) is basically equivalent to a `Producer` from `pipes`.  It's just that the library doesn't provide good tools for working directly with this type and prefers to hide it as an implementation detail.

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez Interesting, I had not stumbled on that before.  Does this functionality exist for Repa and/or Accelerate?  I took a quick look at the module lists for each but didn't see anything that might contain it.

Comment: @bheklir I don't know.  `vector` is the only one of them I've studied in detail.

Comment: Thank you @bheklilr for you detailed answer. I've started to learn Haskell for it's EDSL features and I'm especially interested in code generation for GPU, so you suggestion 2 is not an option for me. As for 3 I've done some coding in this way and went for 1 but due to lack of Haskell experience I did no success. Will you suggest further reading to implement 1 (lot of examples will be an invaluable plus)

Comment: Thank you @GabrielGonzalez for you comment. Don't you know where can I   read more about vector features you mentioned? Any code examples?

Comment: @HounD For implementing 1, you could actually use a combination of Repa and [Pipes](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-4.0.0/docs/Pipes-Tutorial.html), the former to do the processing and the latter to do the streaming.  The basic idea is to read in a large chunk using pipes, then construct a Repa array with those values.  They can then be piped to your number crunching consumer, which then pipes it to the next stage. I can get an example later today. If you're still struggling with parts of Haskell, I would also recommend Learn You A Hs and Real World Hs (google for links, no room).

Comment: @HounD See https://gist.github.com/bheklilr/564c7e66dd6deac9a119 for the code and my comments

Comment: @Hound You can start by reading [this paper](http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.104.7401), which describes how the vector library tries to fuse away intermediate vectors.

Comment: @HounD I've made some changes to that gist, take another look at it to see some different optimization characteristics

Comment: Thank you @bheklilr, I need some time to meditate on you code :)